# Laravel Eloquent best practice reading entries including relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Model called "Services" and another called "Licenses". A Service has many licenses and a licenses belongs to one service.

When I want to return all services including their licenses I currently do the following

```
$services = Auth::user()->services;
foreach($services as $service) {
    $service->licenses;
}
```

This is working, but I'd love to have something cleaner since I use this very often and sometimes in very deep structures.

Comment: Try : $services = Services::all();

Comment: This is not what I want. I do not want all services I'm looking for something like "->services->deep" so that all relations are returned aswell

Comment: You can use https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to post this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to load all the related records, you can do so using eager loading or lazy eager loading, both of which accept nested relationships.

In your example, since you already have the User loaded, you can use the `load()` method to lazy eager load the related records:

```
Auth::user()->load('services.licenses');
dd(Auth::user());
```

Regular eager loading works the same way:

```
$user = User::with('services.licenses')->find(Auth::user()->id);
dd($user);
```

Comment: If Licenses would have another relationship - is there a way to load this too using eager loading? ( AUth::user()->load('services.licenses.example') ?

Comment: @FrankProvost Yes, there is no restriction on how deeply your nested relationships can be (other than your available memory, of course).